# How to implement merge sort using LinkedList?

Tags: java, mergesort

I'm trying to implement merge sort using LinkedList and come to this so far,

```
class Node{


Node next;
int data;

public Node (){

}

public Node(int _data){

    this.data = _data;
   }
  }


 public  class myTest{

   private static Node head;
   private static Node current; 

   public void myTest(){

    this.head = null;
    this.current = null;
}

public static void insert( int data ){

    Node newNode = new Node(data);

    if (head == null){

        head = newNode;
        current = head;
    }

    else {

        current.next = newNode;
        current = newNode;
    }
}

public static void display(Node cur ){

    while( cur != null){

        if (cur.next != null){
            System.out.print(cur.data + " -> ");
        }

        else{
            System.out.print(cur.data +" ");
        }

        cur = cur.next;
    }

    System.out.println();
}

private static Node mergeSort(Node headOriginal ){

    if (headOriginal == null || headOriginal.next == null ){

        return headOriginal; 
    }

    Node a = headOriginal;
    Node b  = headOriginal.next;

    while( b != null && b.next != null ){

        headOriginal = headOriginal.next;
        b = (b.next).next;
    }

    // split in 2 parts 
    b = headOriginal.next;
    headOriginal.next = null;

    return merge( mergeSort(a), mergeSort(b) );
}


 // sort among the 2 parts
 public static Node merge(Node a, Node b) {

    Node c = new Node();
    Node head_1 = c;

    while ((a != null) && (b != null)) {

        if ( a.data <= b.data ){

            c.next = a;
            c = a;
            a = a.next;
        }

        else {

            c.next = b;
            c = b;
            b = b.next;
        }
    }

    c.next = (a == null) ? b : a;
    return head_1.next;        
}  

public static void main(String[] args ){

    int [] arr = {12, 34, 5, 6, 7};

    for (int j =0; j < arr.length; j++){

        insert( arr[j] );
    }

    mergeSort(head);
    display(head);

  }
}
```

The ***mergeSort*** function takes the original head of the LikedList which is generated from the ***insert*** function. I believe that the function properly creates a sorted LL of ascending order. The ***display*** function suppose to print the LL. In this case it only prints from original head (12) to end of the sorted LL and prints '12->34' . I assume if I can pass the head of newly created sorted LL, it will be able to print the whole sorted LL.

1. Does my program is okay or it needs some improvement to implement merge sort ?
2. How can I get the head of sorted LL to pass inside the ***display*** method ?

Comment: Linked List is a very wrong data structure for using Merge Sort i believe.

Comment: I like to solve different programming questions and this is more about learning and having fun with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is for academic purposes as the comment from Sandeep is correct that a LinkedList is not a suitable data structure for mergesort. And writing your own linked list is also probably not a good idea as the Java API data structures are well designed and well tested!

But for your code, it works perfectly fine! The only mistake is that you are not using the result from your mergesort but your "old" reference to head. If you update your reference it should be fine. Try:

```
head = mergeSort(head);
display(head);
```

in your main method and it should work as desired!

Comment: I was missing the point that I can get the head of the sorted LL by calling 
head = mergeSort(head) and use it later on for the display method. Thanks  for your answer.